# Editing a text file, then displaying it

Tags: python

In my code, I want to insert words into a text file from a user. So I have these words in the text file that must be replaced by the user input, here are the strings must be replaced in the file ,  *adjective*,*plural_noun*,*noun*.

```
file1 = open('Sample.txt', 'w')
*adjective*,*plural_noun*,*noun*,*verb*,*male_first_name* = [
  line.strip() for line in open('Sample.txt')]
for t in *adjective* :
  print(input("enter an adjective: ", file=file1))
  print(input("enter an plural noun: ", file=file1))
  print(input("enter an verb: ", file=file1))
file1.close()
```

Comment: Based on your print statements, I am assuming you are using Python 3? Could you clarify what you are trying to do exactly? Replace words in the text file? Do you mean to read list elements into variables or are those the actual strings (with asterisks around them) needing to be replaced? This is unclear.

Comment: What do the contents of the file look like?

Comment: I've edited the snippet to make it readable, but there are far too many big issues left to give any meaningful help.  For example: when you open 'Sample.txt' for writing it's wiped out -- but on the very next statement you try to read the file you've just wiped out... you can't read a file's previous contents AND write new stuff over that previous content at the same time.  And what are all those `*` making things syntactically invalid?  Why do you loop on `adjective`? Do you see the file= are being passed as an arg to `inout`?  WHY?!  &c...  Work a lot on this and ask again...!

Comment: yes,hmm my text file has strings with the astrisks , i want my program to ask the user to replace those strings and display the edited file, basically like madlibs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little something to get you started...

```
file1 = open('Sample.txt', 'r') 
text = file1.read()
while (text.find('*replace*') != -1):
    inp = raw_input("enter some text to replace: ");
    text = text.replace('*replace*', inp, 1)
print(text)
```

If Sample.txt contains `This is some text to *replace*` and the user input is `xyz`, this code prints:

`This is some text to xyz`

Let's step through it bit by bit:

1. `file1 = open('Sample.txt', 'r')` opens the file for reading (`'r'` means "for reading").
2. `text = file1.read()` reads the content of the file and puts it in the variable `text`.
3. `while (text.find('*replace*') != -1):` looks for occurrences of the string `*replace*` and continues with the indented commands as long as it finds one.
4. `inp = raw_input("enter some text to replace: ")`, which only runs if there is a remaining occurrence of `*replace*`, gets user input and puts it in the variable `inp`.
5. `text = text.replace('*replace*', inp, 1)`, which also only runs if there is a remaining occurrence of `*replace*`, replaces the next occurrence of `*replace*` with the user input, overwriting the old text.
6. `print(text)`, which runs once all occurrences of `*replace*` have been replaced with user input, prints out the new text.

This is not how you would write an efficient programme with lots of different `*string*` strings, but hopefully it will lead you in the right direction and walking before running is often a good idea.

There is excellent [online Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) and you can also use the pydoc tool -- e.g. `pydoc str.replace` from the command line.